# Adding a new line in a JSX string inside a paragraph - React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have the following React code:

```
render() {
  const str = 'Line 1. **new-line** Line 2.';
  return (
    <p> {str} </p>
  );
}
```

I would like the output to be:

```
Line 1.
Line 2.
```

That is - to add a new line between the words. 
I have tried `\n` but it does not work.

How could this be accomplished?

**Edit:** The string is received from a server.

Comment: Did you try string literals?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
and whitespace: pre

Comment: I simplified the question, but in practice I receive the string from a server.. so string literals don't help.

Comment: Then you have to modify the string and put a break in between and use that as html. Just like the gentleman answered.

Comment: @DM, check my updated answer and especially the 2nd code snippet. I think it solves your issue.

Answer (score 84):

Set CSS-Style for the paragraph as below, it will break line on \n and wrap text according to parent width.

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

or

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit about what these do, and what's different?

Comment: **pre-wrap** preserves all white spaces and line breaks. **pre-line** collapses multiple white spaces into one but still preserves line breaks

Answer (score 16):

A more traditional approach is to just create an array with your strings, with a `<br />` tag in between. Arrays are, as of React v16 a valid return value for Elements.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const arr = ['Line 1. ', <br />, 'Line 2.'];
    return (
      <p> {arr} </p>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If you are getting a string from some API, you could create such an array by finding all `<br />` substrings and replace them with actual JSX `<br />`'s. The following code will take your string and do a string split on every instance of `<br />`. This will give you `['Line 1. ', '', 'Line 2.']`. As you can see, every odd element in the array is where we want to push a JSX `<br />`. We can do that quite simply in a loop.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const str = 'Line 1. <br /> Line 2.';
    const arr = str.split(/<br \/>/);
    const resultArr = [];
    arr.forEach((item, i) => {
      if(i%2===0) resultArr.push(<br />);
      resultArr.push(item);      
    });
    return (
      <p> {resultArr} </p>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

The other approach is to either use `dangeourslySetInnerHTML()` or use template literals.

You could use template literals for that along with the css rule `white-space: pre` to preserve newlines. See my demo below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const str = `Line 1.  
 Line 2.`;
    return (
      <p style={{whiteSpace: 'pre'}}> {str} </p>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 11):

```
style={{ whiteSpace: 'break-spaces' }}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could accomplish this by using CSS instead.

```
p {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

You render then becomes:

```
const str = "Line 1.\nLine 2."
return (<p>{str}</p>)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using CSS - (Simply add it to content's div. Wraps and adds new-line for every '\n' appended to content)

```
p {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Use React's dangerouslySetInnerHTML - (Apply to parents div and parse any tags in the value field. Works similar to innerHTML.)

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<p>First &middot; Second</p>'}}></div>
```

Link for more information about dangerouslySetInnerHTML:
[https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml][1]

Comment: Thanks man! this is exactly what I was looking for. The rest of the answers don't take into account that maybe I am passing the text using a prop...

Answer (score 3):

For that purpose you have to use something called `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

**Example**

```
render() {
  const str = 'Line 1. <br /> Line 2.';
  return (
    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: str }}/>
  );
}
```

Comment: This seems dangerous... Isn;t there some kind of ascii code that can output a newline?

Comment: This is not dangerous. They are just kind of imforming you that there is a possibility of `cross site scripting` attack. But you can actually prevent it. By `normalizing the HTML` content in the server response or before rendering the content.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do.

```html
<span>{<br/>}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it by doing the following:

```
myTextHere={<span>Hello<br />Hi</span>}
```

Output will be like this:

```
Hello
Hi
```

Answer (score 0):

Open this html page with your browser.

Mine is chromium 115.0.5790.98

#ExampalReactNewLines.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>ExampalReactNewLines</title>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js'></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script type='text/babel'>
function ExampalReactNewLines() 
{

return (
    
<div>    
{`

1 newline

2 newline

3 newline


7 newline





2 newline


15 newline














stop
`.split(/\n{100}/).map((i,key) => {return <pre key={key}>{i}</pre>;})
}    

</div>
 )
}




















/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
      
      
      
      ReactDOM.render(<ExampalReactNewLines />, document.querySelector('#root'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```