# Using white-space: pre-line with string from API in React with Mongo

Tags: reactjs

I have a string which I receive by calling a Server which is using Mongo. (The string is stored inside mongo).

This is the string: `"Line 1\nLine 2"`.

I would like to show the string inside a `<p>` in React.

Following an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229792/adding-a-new-line-in-a-jsx-string-inside-a-paragraph-react)  question I've tried:

In React js:

```
<p>{str}</p>
```

In css:

```
p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

It works when `str="Line 1\nLine 2"`

But when I fetch the same string from API (Server with Mongo) it doesn't work!

Why?

*Edit:* I receive the string from an Express Server by sending a GET request and receiving the response. The server is connected to the Mongo Sever

Comment: what is the API response?

Comment: Also, how do you fetch it from the API?

Comment: I've added the info to the question.

Comment: Show the actual response from API

Comment: post the exact response text you are getting from api call so that we can understand what the problem is