# Importing Json Strings in jsx File not detecting \n new lines

Tags: json, reactjs, jsx

I am importing text through a json file into my React jsx file to display. However when I type new lines in my json file as '\n' or '\r' , they do not appear as line breaks in my output.

example.json file:

```
{
"text": "some text here and a \n line break"
}
```

example.jsx file:

```
import { text } from "./example.json"
const foo = text
render() {
    return <div> {foo} <div>
}
```

Output:

```
some text here and a line break
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229792/adding-a-new-line-in-a-jsx-string-inside-a-paragraph-react?. Try `<div style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap'}}>{foo} </div>` (Don't forget to close your `div` tag).

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!