# Insert a list inside a TextField

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i have a list like this

```
const list = ["joe", "stack overflow", "gitlab", "hello React!!!"]
```

and i want to put this list in a text field separated by end line "\n"

i tried getting the values from the array like this

```
 const values =  Array.of(list).join("\n")
```

but i get the value separated by comma instead of a end line,is there another way i can do this.

Comment: your `list` should have the `join` method on its prototype.

Comment: You've tagged the question with React, so I guess you want [each string on a new line in the resulting HTML on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50229792/1218980)

Answer (score 3):

`Array.of([1,2,3])` results in `[ [1,2,3] ]` - an array with a single element at index 0 which happens to be your array.

As others have pointed out, just do `[1,2,3].join("\n")`. But this answer tells you why.

[Docs for Array.of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of)

Answer (score 2):

Just do :

```js
const values = list.join("\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

`["joe", "stack overflow", "gitlab", "hello React!!!"].join("\n")` works for me.

Answer (score 2):

```js
list.join("\n")
```

did the job for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try without 'Array.of'

```js
let list = ["joe", "stack overflow", "gitlab", "hello React!!!"]

const values = list.join("\n") 

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

This does it for me.

```
const list = ["joe", "stack overflow", "gitlab", "hello React!!!"]
let values = list.join("\n");
console.log(values);


// result

joe
stack overflow
gitlab
hello React!!!
```