# How to add a line break in JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to add a line break to the following array. Using **\n** doesn't seem to work.

```
const output = {
  message: [
      `Hello world\n Hello again!`
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to add line breaks in arrays? I tried mapping through the array and adding some HTML but didn't have much success there as I couldn't figure out how to separate the **"Hello World"** and **"Hello again"** messages:

```
const displayOutput = output.message.map((messages, id) =>
      <p key={id} className="output-message">
        {messages}
      </p>
 );
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: newline characters are not shown as new lines when put in html, use a `<br>` or css styling

Comment: Or something more React-specific, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50229792/3001761.

Comment: Thanks, yes the react specific example worked for me.

Comment: Line breaks `\n` are ignored by HTML without some specific CSS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n

Answer (score -2):

You are using a template literal, which means that linebreaks are defined by actually making a newline in the string itself.

Comment: Line breaks `\n` are ignored by HTML without some specific CSS.